# Connecting to external database with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to have access to my vbulletin forum database on other server than my rails app.
I created `vbulletin` entry in `database.yml`

```
vbulletin:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: latin2
  database: db_name
  username: username
  password: password
  host: forum.hostname.pl
  port: 3306
```

And created simple model `vbuser.rb`

```
class Vbuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:vbulletin)
  self.table_name = 'user'
end
```

Now, I'm trying run `Vbuser.last` in console but get : 
`Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'forum.hostname.pl' (110)`

What can be the problem?

Comment: Using an admin console, can you connect to the database with the details you've got in your database.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons I can think of -:Either you have supplied incorrect details, or the host does not allow you to directly connect. Don't think it's a Rails specific issue. Can you do a quick check on some other language (php etc) and see if you are able to connect? Your syntax seems fine to me.

To quickly check create a connect.php file on localhost.

In that file

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect('host','user','pwd','database') or die("can't connect");
if ($link)
echo "Working";
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

What do you get?

Comment: just run `telnet forum.hostname.pl 3306` and get `Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`. Just waiting for my admin info, maybe he blocks external connections? ps. your script gives the same result `Can't connect to MySQL`. At least I know it's not Rails problem, thanks.

Comment: Problem was both db user priviliges and firewall settings.